# Can I delete files in my 'Local Settings's 'Temp' and 'Application Data' directories?

Tags: windows-xp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What files are in local settings/temp and can I delete them?](https://superuser.com/questions/47098/what-files-are-in-local-settings-temp-and-can-i-delete-them)

I am running out of space on my hard drive and I see 3 GB of space being taken up by this 'Local Settings' / 'Temp' directory:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\[MyName]\Local Settings\Temp
```

Can I delete this? What are the implications?

Also, `C:\Documents and Settings\[MyName]\Local Settings\Application Data` seems to be taking up a lot of space as well?